# Making part of th tag unbold in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have two questions:

1. I have a `th` tg in my table like this:

   ```
   <th style="background-color: #ffebcd" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Key: {{getValue()}}</th>
   ```

Currently, both the title `Key` and associated data, both appear as bold. I want only `Key` should appear bold, while the data is un-bold when fetched from JS function. I tried using the `<span>` tag and specifying using `class` a CSS denoting `font-weight: normal`. But it looks like `<span` doesn't work inside `th` tag.

2. I have table header which spans across two rows, i.e. `rowspan=2`. I want that the text in this appears in the middle of the two cells. Using `text-align: center` shifts along x-axis. I am talking about shifting about the y-axis so that the text appears in center. Picture is attached for reference. I want the hello to appear in the middle of the cell along the y-axis as well.

   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the Key word in a `strong` tag.

```css
th {
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #ffebcd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
      <span><strong>Key</strong>: {{getValue()}} </span>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample value</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As a general rule of thumb - inline css is really hard to maintain, so look to move it to a separate style.css file.

Comment: would you be knowing how to do the #2 question above as well? How to move text to center wrt to y axis?

Comment: can you advice on how I can add a hyperlink in this?

Comment: Yes, so, in my case, I want to have the URL as, `google.com/SampleValue` where this SampleValue is fetched from a function. Therefore, I did something like this, `<a href="https://example.com/browse/{}">{{getValue(key)}}</a>` but this doesn't work. It doesn't properly replace the curly braces with the function value.